# Facebook Chat with centralized server

Tags: facebook, chat, xmpp

Is it possible to implement a Facebook chat client through centralized server? My centralized server get and coordinate the chat for users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a xmpp server on your server, try [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp).

The same community make a xmpp web client, [SparkWeb](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/sparkweb/index.jsp)

If you want to make it look/act like the fb chat, you need to learn how to use ajax/javascript/php.